# Extending a function from a compact subspace to the whole space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, complex-numbers

Given a compact subspace $A\subset X$ of a compact Hausdorff space $X$, can any continuous function $f:A\to \Bbb C$ be extended to a function $X\to \Bbb C$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes by [Tietze's Extension Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem). (Regard a map to $\Bbb C$ as a pair
of maps to $\Bbb R$ by considering real and imaginary parts.)

Comment: Does this work if I replace $\Bbb C$ by some other Hausdorff space?

Comment: It will work for $\Bbb R^n$ but not for general Hausdorff spaces.